# need mathematica to tell me the coordinates of the edges of the infinite plane

Tags: graphics3d

Just need some help getting Mathematica to tell me the coordinates "back". I have given points to InfinitePlane[] and now I would like to know the points at which the infinite plane meets the edges of the box that Mathematica draws around my Graphics3D model. In other words, I would like to extend my coordinates to the edges of the box.  thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica SE. Please paste your code so we can understand your problem better. Perhaps you could include `PlotRange`  as one of your Graphics3D arguments. something like: `Graphics3D[InfinitePlane[{{1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1}}],PlotRange -> {{-10,10},{-10,10},{-10,10}}] `